# How to test event using Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I need to test event.
I raise an event in the class but I didn't get it in my test.
What is the reason?
The Object_TransferInterruptedEvent1 is newer executed.
This is demo code.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual event EventHandler<EventArgs<Tuple<Step, string>>> TransferInterruptedEvent;

    public void Test()
    {
         this.OnEventTransferInterrupted(this.CurrentStep, "Transfer not valid");
    }

    protected void OnEventTransferInterrupted(Step step, string errorMsg)
    {
        if (this.TransferInterruptedEvent != null)
        {
            this.TransferInterruptedEvent(this,new EventArgs<Tuple<object, string>>(new Tuple<object, string>(step, errorMsg)));
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
var mock=new Mock<A>()
EventArgs<Tuple<S3Server.Step, string>>  mess;
mock.Object.TransferInterruptedEvent += Object_TransferInterruptedEvent1;
mock.Object.Test(); 

Assert.IsTrue(mess.Value.Item1 == S3Server.Step.TransferValidation);
Assert.IsTrue(mess.Value.Item2 == "Transfer not valid");

private void Object_TransferInterruptedEvent1(object sender, EventArgs<Tuple<object, string>> e) {
    mess=e;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the mock to call the base class. by setting `mock.CallBase = true;` This will allow the mocking framework to assign the event subscription.

```
[TestMethod]
public void _MockEvent() {
    //Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<A>();
    mock.CallBase = true;
    EventArgs<Tuple<Step, string>> mess = null;

    mock.Object.TransferInterruptedEvent += delegate(object sender, EventArgs<Tuple<Step, string>> e) {
        mess = e;
    };

    //Act
    mock.Object.Test();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(mess);
    Assert.IsTrue(mess.Value.Item1 == Step.TransferValidation);
    Assert.IsTrue(mess.Value.Item2 == "Transfer not valid");
}
```